# ¿ayuda para multiplicar dos matrices?

Tags: lista, matrices, numpy

Estoy realizando un programa donde necesito multiplicar la siguientes matrices:

> [[-13.   6.  -4.]  [ 12.  -5.   3.]  [ -5.   2.  -1.]]

Esta matriz que es una inversa de otra que saque de esta manera:

```
matriz_lista = np.array(lista_tempL).reshape(3,-1)  
b = np.linalg.inv(matriz_lista)
```

y esta matriz:

> [[25 19 15 15 18 15]  [ 6  0 28  0 21  0]  [27  3  6  8  2  8]]

las estoy tratando de multiplicar asi:

```
matrizf = b*matriz_mensaje
```

y me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3)
>   (3,6)

he multiplicado ambas matrices en calculadoras en linea y se pueden multiplicar no se que pasa

Comment: Intentalo asi: `matrizf = matriz_mensaje*b`

Comment: lo mismo, intente pero funciono

Comment: Intenta esto `matrizf = b.dot(matriz_mensaje)`

Comment: eso hice y lo logre, de esta forma:

Comment: matrizf= np.dot(b,matriz_mensaje)

Comment: muchas gracias .